# Find if vector is subvector c++

Tags: c++, vector

Assume that I have:

```
std::vector<string> group;
std::vector<string> subGroup;
```

Some properties about those two vectors:

1) All elements are unique.

2) They're not sorted, and sorting is not an option.

I need to check if group contains subgroup. If it does, than I need to return true, if it doesn't return false.

Examples:

group = {"A","B","C","D"}, subGroup = {"A","D","E"} -> answer = false

group = {"A","E","C","D"}, subGroup = {"A","D","E"} -> answer = true

My current implementation is:

```
int cont=0;
if(subGroup.size() > group.size())
    return false;
else{
    for(int i=0; i<subGroup.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<group.size(); j++){
            if(subGroup[i] == group[j]{
                cont++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (cont == subGroup.size())
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

I checked on this post here [locate sub-vector<string> in another vector<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388840/locate-sub-vectorstring-in-another-vectorstring) , but I'm not supposed to use C++11 features and also this answer does not solve my problem (using my example 2 for instance, it will return false).

Two things: is my implementation ok or is there any mistakes? Is there an easier way to implement it using STL features or anything like it?

Comment: Why is sorting not an option?

Comment: Because the order of both vectors are important. As a matter of fact, I can copy both, sort the copies and check what I need to check, but isn't it worst (in terms of complexity and space usage) to do?

Comment: For starters, you dont need the very first else.  if you returned your done.... 
If you want to check if your implementation is ok, then you should write some examples to test it with trying various border conditions.

Comment: If order is important, then if sub group is A,E,D do all of them return false?

Comment: one thing def bad, is j=0; start j at whatever value i is at.  otherwise you're violating your sorting order stuff you mentioned...  oh wait... you just changed your data...

Comment: Order is important in another part of the program. Like I told Hurkyl, I can make a copy and sort the copy. Still, isn't it worst?

Comment: woz, then specify that clearly in your question.  Functions don't care about other sections. What matters is how you pass them to the function.. If you need them to be unchanged outside of the function, pass by value and let them be copied potentially.  (And dont tell us we cant sort them).. If they can't be sorted PERIOD because say order matters for this function then say that. :-)

Comment: Performance is a complicated topic. Generally speaking, trying to reason out whether one thing is more efficient than another gives poor results, especially if you don't have extensive experience with optimizing the sorts of things you're implementing as well as the machine you're implementing it on. Best results come from actually implementing alternatives and testing them in a wide variety of use cases.

Comment: I changed a part of the code which had a "break" instruction. It was definitely wrong. Also, I realized that sorting then in one of my functions wouldn't be a problem at all. Stupid me :D

Comment: @Hurkyl Couldn't have said it better!

Comment: @woz Why are you not allowed to use C++11 features?

Comment: @Zereges teacher's orders haha

Comment: @woz, doesn't seem like a very pragmatic teacher to me if he/she won't let you use C++11/14

Comment: @Alejandro I agree. He will teach us to use those features after this assignment. I think his idea is to show how "hard" it is to implement everything without using some features, then teach us the features.

Comment: @woz: That's like teaching you how to drive by starting with a horse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two most straightforward solutions are:

- Copy the vectors, sort them, then use [includes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/includes/)
- Copy the elements of a group into a `set` or an `unordered_set`, and then check each element of `subgroup` to see if it's in the set (if C++11 were an option, you could use [`all_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/) and a lambda to implement the loop)

  - A variant on the same idea: make a `set` or an `unordered_set` out of the elements of `subgroup`, then loop through the elements of `group`, removing them from the set if present. Return `true` iff this empties out the set.

In either case, to get reasonable worst case performance guarantees you should immediately return false if `subgroup` is larger in size than `group`.

The latter, with `unordered_set`, has the best asymptotic complexity you can possibly expect (i.e. `O(n)` where `n` is the size of `group`), but I imagine the first option will be more efficient for "typical" examples.

Comment: Might be helpful to invert the iteration order... iterate tightly over your group of candidates, and make a single pass through the larger `group` vector/set etc.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: Hrm. You mean something like making a set out of the elements of `subgroup` and then make a loop that goes over the elements of `group` and removes them from the set if present, and declare success if the set is empty at the end? Yah, that would probably work even better

Comment: Yes.  Searching the smaller set since it is more likely to be able to be kept hot in cache which is good since we'll be repeatedly accessing the same elements...  even that is gonna depend on dimensions/size of data though

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple solution to this problem, using [std:find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/?kw=find):

```
bool            in(std::vector<std::string> const &group,
                   std::vector<std::string> const &subGroup) {
  std::size_t const     subSize = subGroup.size();
  int                   i = 0;

  while (i < subSize && std::find(group.begin(), group.end(), subGroup[i]) != group.end()) {
    i++;
  }
  return (i == subSize);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use a `std::set`

```
std::set<std::string> group ; // Fill it first !

std::vector<std::string> subgroups  {"A","D","E"} ;
std::vector<std::string>::iterator i = subgroups.begin() ;

std::pair<std::set<std::string>::iterator,bool> p;

for( ; i != subgroups.end(); ++i )
{
    p = group.insert( *i );
    if( p.second ) // Present in group
    {
             break;
    }
}

if( i == subgroups.end() )
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << true ;
else
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << false ;
```

Comment: Tried to use it but after including <set> i got: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert' p = group.insert( *i ); . Suggestions?

Comment: @woz So you asked me to code for you, so [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b639aa0a5ea056e4) it is